# Finding a pattern and extracting strings

Tags: regex, r

I'm trying to scrap a website I'm a newbie using regular expressions. I have a long character vector, this is the line that I'm aiming:

```
<h3 class=\"title4\">Results: <span id=\"hitCount.top\">10,079</span></h3>\n
```

I want to extract the number that it is in between `<span id=\"hitCount.top\">` and `</span>`. In this case 10,079. My approach so far, though, not really working.

```
x <- '<h3 class=\"title4\">Results: <span id=\"hitCount.top\">10,079</span>'
m <- gregexpr(pattern="[<span id=\"hitCount.top\">].+[</span>]", x, ignore.case = FALSE, perl = FALSE,
         fixed = FALSE, useBytes = FALSE)
regmatches(x, m)
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: `sub("<span id=\"hitCount.top\">(.*?)<.*", "\\1", x)`

Comment: Why not obtain the plain text value and get the number from it? It would be "cleaner".

Comment: You are using character class..That will match any character from `[]` and not whole string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to illustrate how easy it may become if you are using `XML` package:

```
> library("XML")
> url = "PATH_TO_HTML"
> parsed_doc = htmlParse(file=url, useInternalNodes = TRUE)
> h3title4 <- getNodeSet(doc = parsed_doc, path = "//h3[@class='title4']")
> plain_text <- sapply(h3title4, xmlValue)
> plain_text
[1] "Results: 10,079"
> sub("\\D*", "", plain_text)
[1] "10,079"
```

The `sub("\\D*", "", plain_text)` line will remove the first chunk of 0+ non-digits in the input, that is, `\D*` will match `Results:`  and will replace it with an empty string.

The example HTML I used was

```html
<html>
<body>
<h3 class="title4">Results: <span id="hitCount.top">10,079</span></h3>
<img width="10%" height="10%" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/fe/Green-Up-Arrow.svg/2000px-Green-Up-Arrow.svg.png"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `stringr` library

```
> library(stringr)
> str_extract(x, "(?<=<span id=\"hitCount.top\">)(.*?)(?=</span>)")
[1] "10,079"
```

Using `gsub` (`sub` can also be used here instead of `gsub`)

```
> gsub(".*<span id=\"hitCount.top\">(.*?)</span>.*", "\\1", x)
[1] "10,079"
```